# Null Pointer Exception / Not Found Exception when I tried to process & sink data in Avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am using a processor to consume byte array data with byte array serdes from a topic, process them into a generic record (based on schema I got from my HTTP GET request) and send them over to a topic with formatted avro schema registry.

I had no problem retrieving the schema from HTTP GET request and map my data according to it to generate a generic record that follows the schema. However when I tried to sink it to the topic I get a Null Pointer Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
atio.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.
    java:72        )
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54)
at 
   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:78)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:79)
atorg.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl
     .java:83)
at streamProcessor.XXXXprocessor.process(XXXXprocessor.java:80)
at streamProcessor.XXXXprocessor.process(XXXXprocessor.java:1)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:48)
atorg.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetr
    icsImpl.java:188)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:134)
atorg.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl
    .java:111)
at streamProcessor.SelectorProcessor.process(SelectorProcessor.java:33)
at streamProcessor.SelectorProcessor.process(SelectorProcessor.java:1)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:48)
atorg.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetr
    icsImpl.java:188)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:134)
atorg.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl
    .java:83)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:70)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:197)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:627)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:361)
```

This is my topology code:

```
//Stream Properties
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "processor-kafka-streams234");
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx");
config.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
config.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());

config.put(StreamsConfig.TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, 
        WallclockTimestampExtractor.class);



//Build topology
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.addSource("messages-source", "mytest2");
builder.addProcessor("selector-processor", () -> new SelectorProcessor(), "messages-source");

builder.addProcessor("XXXX-processor", () -> new XXXXprocessor(), "selector-processor");
builder.addSink("XXXX-sink", "XXXXavrotest", new KafkaAvroSerializer(), new               
        KafkaAvroSerializer(), "XXXX-processor");



//Start Streaming
KafkaStreams streaming = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
streaming.start();
System.out.println("processor streaming...");
```

After some readings on the issues forum I discovered that I might need to inject a client when I am creating the `KafkaAvroSerializer`s, so I changed that line to:

```
  SchemaRegistryClient client = new 
  CachedSchemaRegistryClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx/subjects/xxxxschemas/versions", 1000);
  builder.addSink("XXXX-sink", "XXXXavrotest", new KafkaAvroSerializer(client), new 
  KafkaAvroSerializer(client), "XXXX-processor");
```

Which resulted in a HTTP 404 Not Found Exception ...

Comment: I guess you don't need the client, but to add the schema registry url to your StreamsConfig: `config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "your-URL");`

Comment: Compare: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I had my URL wrong :P

Also the key had to be init to something besides null because of the cleanup.policy setting on my topic.